# How to debug? emacs lisp program behavior does not achieve the desired but the executing the same as command does?

Tags: elisp, org-mode

In a test buffer in emacs with Spacemacs, I have the following (the problem is also described in the buffer content):

```
* Top Heading

** A subheading created by executing commands

M-x org-insert-heading
M-x org-do-demote

Below I tried to achieve the same with an elisp function:

*** A subheading created by executing an interactive elisp function still works
It also works. Here is the program:

(defun org-insert-subheading-relative ()
  "Replacement of org-insert-subheading, as it requires to provide an argument,
   which is not convenient to program."
  (interactive)
  (org-insert-heading)
  (org-do-demote)
  )

However, having the code segment below,
 the (org-do-demote) would not work, in
the following code segment:

(progn
            (goto-end-of-code-block)
            (insert "\n")
            (org-insert-heading)
            (org-do-demote)
            (insert block)
            (hide-subtree)
            )
```

What could be the cause of the problem?

Here is the related code not defined by standard emacs:

```
(defun goto-end-of-code-block ()
  (re-search-forward "#\\+END_SRC.*$" nil t 1) ; no raising error
  )
```

Comment: What is `goto-end-of-code-block`? It's not defined in my Emacs. What happens when you execute your `progn` block? Do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I've added the definition of ```goto-end-of-code-block```

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've just tried it and it seems to work in my emacs, if the behaviour you are after is that it inserts a newline and a new demoted header below the code block. Perhaps you could try temporarily removing your config and just using a plain vanilla emacs?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'll try to isolate my problem.